# How to DSA certification key size using openssl API

Tags: c, c++11, openssl

I used "key_size = RSA_size(rsa_key)' to get the RSA key size, but when i used 'key_size = DSA_size(dsa_key)' i am unable to get the exact key-size, is there any other API other than yhese to get the certification size.